# InfoPath 2010 Custom Ribbon with Custom Commands

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

Has anyone found a way to customize InfoPath 2010 form ribbon for SP 2013/2016 to add custom commands such as workflow initiations and approval buttons?

Also, is there a way to save the form and after save to redirect to view mode of that item rather than going back to a (large) list of items?

Thanks.